# looping in xslt between two different numbers

Tags: php, xml, dom, xslt

i have two nodes in my xml, which are generated dynamically

```
  <xml>
    <start>4</start>
    <end>14</end>
  </xml>
```

i want to loop between start to end in the select box, i tried something like below but its showing single value.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/doc/start[position() &lt;= /doc/end]">
  <option value=""><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></option>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

actually what i wanted is to generate dynamic options in select box using values from nodes.like

```
<select>
   <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option> --- so on till end value

</select>
```

i have solved above issue using recursive template , below is my solution

```
  <select class="small" name="" >
<xsl:call-template name="ascYear">
    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="/doc/start"/>
</xsl:call-template>
  </select>
  <xsl:template name="ascYear">
  <xsl:param name="count" select="1"/>
  <xsl:if test="$count &lt;= doc/end">
    <option value="{$count}"><xsl:value-of select="$count"/></option>
    <xsl:call-template name="ascYear">
      <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

hope it helps someone

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "the select box". Could you post the expected result?

Comment: If you've been able to solve your problem, please post it as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my above problem

```
<select class="small" name="" >
<xsl:call-template name="ascYear">
<xsl:with-param name="count" select="/doc/start"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</select>
<xsl:template name="ascYear">
<xsl:param name="count" select="1"/>
<xsl:if test="$count &lt;= doc/end">
<option value="{$count}"><xsl:value-of select="$count"/></option>
<xsl:call-template name="ascYear">
  <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

if someone has more better and efficient solution, please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to make the call-template context independent, so you can use it even if the xml format changes.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <select>
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-options">
            <xsl:with-param name="current" select="xml/start"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="end" select="xml/end"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </select>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="generate-options">
    <xsl:param name="current"/>
    <xsl:param name="end"/>

    <xsl:if test="$current &lt;= $end">
        <option><xsl:value-of select="$current"/></option>
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-options">
            <xsl:with-param name="current" select="$current + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="end" select="$end"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Working example: http://xsltransform.net/b4GWV6/1

Comment: A point of good practice: check your exit condition **before** generating the option. Otherwise you *will* get a result when calling the template with current > end.

Comment: true, otherwise i could have an option element even if start is greater then end. I will correct the answer...